# How to add every other columns together in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I've been cracking my head over the addition of every 'other' columns together during aggregation in Mongo.

A sample of my data:

```
[
{'item': 'X',
'USA': 3,
'CAN': 1,
'CHN': 1,
'IDN': 1,
   :
   :
   :
},
{'item': 'R',
'USA': 2,
'CAN': 2,
'CHN': 1,
'IDN': 2,
   :
   :
   :
}
]
```

**At the aggregate stage**, I would like to have **a new field called 'OTHER'**, which is the resultant of the **summation of all the fields that are not specified**.

My desired result is this:

```
[
{'item': 'X',
'NAM': 79,
'IDN': 51,
'OTHER': 32
},
{'item': 'R',
'NAM': 42,
'IDN': 11,
'OTHER': 20
}
]
```

So far, the closest I could get is using this:

```
mycoll.aggregate([
{'$addFields':{
            'NAM': {'$add':[{'$ifNull':['$CAN', 0]},{'$ifNull':['$USA', 0]}]},
            'INDIA': {'$ifNull':['$IDN', 0]},
            'OTHER': /* $add all the fields that are not $USA, $CAN, $IDN*/
}},
])
```

Mongo gurus, please enlighten this poor soul. Deeply appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain this ***/* $add all the fields that are not $USA, $CAN, $IDN*/***

Comment: I want to add those fields which are not USA, CAN, IDN together to create a new field 'OTHER'

Answer (score 3):

In general the idea is converting your document to an array so we could iterate over it while ignoring unwanted fields.

```
 {
     '$addFields': {
         'NAM': {'$add': [{'$ifNull': ['$CAN', 0]}, {'$ifNull': ['$USA', 0]}]},
         'INDIA': {'$ifNull': ['$IDN', 0]},
         "OTHER": {
             $reduce:
                 {
                     input: {"$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"},
                     initialValue: {sum: 0},
                     in: {
                         sum: {
                             $cond: {
                                 if: {$in: ["$$this.k", ['_id', "item", "CAN", "USA", "IDN"]]},
                                 then: "$$value.sum",
                                 else: {$add: ["$$value.sum", "$$this.v"]}
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
         }

     }
 }
```

Obivously you should also add any other fields that you have in your document that you do not want to sum up / are not of type number.